# Difference Between Angular's @HostBinding( 'window:resize' ) And Rxjs' fromEvent( window, 'resize' )

Tags: angular, observable, settimeout

I am just wondering what advantages there are using the one instead of the other.

```
@HostListener( 'window:resize' )
doSomething(): void {
    // ...throttle with setTimeout and clearTimeout maybe...
}
```

and

```
fromEvent( window, 'resize' ).pipe(
    // ... debounceTime, takeUntil etc.
).subscribe( () => {
    doSomething();
})
```

Is it really just a question of context (e.g. easier handling the stream of events by using pipe() ), or is the observable more «mordern», or doesn't it matter at all?

Thanks!

Comment: The question is primarily opinionated. IMO, subjectively, `fromEvent` provides more robust ways to handle an event compared to `HostListener` decorator. Moreover `HostListener` is Angular specific whereas `fromEvent` could theoretically be included in any JS app that uses RxJS. See [here](https://dev.to/angular/ain-t-nobody-needs-hostlistener-fg4) for a quick comparison.

Comment: @MichaelD You know, there's a close reason for that...

Answer (score 6):

The `fromEvent` will give you more flexibility with execution and pipe lining as well as the possibility to bind outside of the `NgZone` context.

The `@Hostlistener` has an advantage where you don't have to manually trigger the change detection after an event is fired. You do need to that with `Observables` when your component uses the `OnPush` change detection strategy, which is the advised (but not default) strategy. There are other cases where you need to do this when using `fromEvent`, but those are very much edge cases.

Another advantage of `HostListener` is that you don't need to unsubscribe when the component destroys, as this is done automatically.

So mainly, it's all about preference and context.

<sub>ad</sub>
There are third party [libraries](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ng-event-options) (mine) out there which extend the `HostListener` and template event binding stuff with debounce and other cool features.

Comment: Thanks for sharing your library. Good to be aware of it