# How to trigger window resize on width changes only

Tags: angular, typescript, resize

I need to apply some custom styling on an element based on the window's current screenWidth.

That's successfully done by using the following @HostListener:

```
 @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
  public resize() {

   // apply styles here depending on current window.innerWidth...

  }
```

However, I want to trigger the resize method **ONLY** when window's **width** has changed and **do nothing when height has changed**.

The way it is so far, the resize method is also called if the user changes the window height and that is breaking my styling logic!

So my question is: Is there a way in Angular to make something like ('window:resizeX') in order to call resize() only when window width changes, ignoring changes on window height?

Comment: I guess the best way of doing it is to store previous window width and compare it to new width inside `resize` function. something like `private windowOldWidth: number = window.innerWidth` and `resize() {  if(this.windowOldWidth === window.innerWidth) { return; } this.windowOldWidth = window.innerWidth; // rest of logic here }`

Comment: Thanx for the insight. That successfully solved my issue!

Comment: why not use [css media querys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries)?

Comment: Indeed media queries are the overall go-to approach, but sometimes you need to do something with javascript in response to window changes. That's when media queries are not super great

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use this method:

```
fromEvent(window, 'resize')
  .pipe(map(() => window.innerWidth), distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe(() => this.onResize());
```

and if you want some optimization then use auditTime():

```
fromEvent(window, 'resize')
  .pipe(auditTime(100), map(() => window.innerWidth), distinctUntilChanged())
  .subscribe(() => this.onResize());
```

so your method will run not often than every 100ms

Answer (score 3):

The main common ways to listen to the resize are

1. fromEvent(window, 'resize')
2. @HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])

both of them have some advantages over the other, mainly, it's all about preference and context.

Check this [fromevent window vs hostlistener](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66030103/5758316).

@Oleg gave the fix of your issue using fromEvent operator, If you need the fix using the HostListener way. it could be like that.

```
private lastScreenWidth;
....

ngAfterViewInit(){
    this.lastScreenWidth = window.innerWidth;
}

@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
private resize(event) {
    if (event.target.innerWidth !== this.lastScreenWidth) {
        // Do your staff based on window width resize..
        this.lastScreenWidth = event.target.innerWidth;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Oleg Postoev is right, that the best way to go.

This version only fires if the width is constant for a bit (800ms);

```
fromEvent(window, 'resize').pipe(
  debounceTime(800),
  tap((event: UIEvent) => {
    const width = event.target['innerWidth'];
    // DO SOMETHING
  }, takeUntil(this.unsubscribe$)) // CLEANUP
).subscribe();
```